# How to draw svg shapes next to each other without a viewbox for each

Tags: css, svg

I found a codepen with letters.

https://codepen.io/scnijland/pen/xRGjBw

Question: How can I write the shapes next to each other in one SVG with one line each? When I try, the letters are overlapping badly.

I would like

```
<svg .....>
  <path for letter a />
  <path for letter b />
  <path for letter c />
</svg>
```

Eventually if possible I would like to have the letters randomly produced, stroke by stroke

```
<svg .....>
  <path for left downstroke letter a />
  <path for right downstroke letter a />
  <path for bridge letter a />
  <path for vertical bar letter b />
  <path for top arch letter b />
  <path for bottom arch letter b />
  <path for top half arch letter c />
  <path for bottom half arch letter c />
</svg>
```

---

Snippet:

```css
svg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  stroke: #000;
}
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<svg class="letter--a" viewBox="0 0 80 100">
  <path d="M5,90
           l30,-80 30,80
           M20,50
           l30,0" />
</svg>
<svg class="letter--b" viewBox="0 0 80 100">
  <path d="M5,5
           c80,0 80,45 0,45
           c80,0 80,45 0,45z" />
</svg>
<svg class="letter--c" viewBox="0 0 80 100">
  <path d="M60,10
           C-10,0 -10,100 60,90" />
</svg>
```

Comment: For the "letter pieces" part of your question, the simplest answer would be to load your letters into an SVG editor (like Inkscape) and split the letters up into separate paths for the pieces you want.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau that is an interesting scenario

Comment: It's possible to do it by duplicating the paths and using `stroke-dasharray` to display parts of each one. But it's going to be a lot easier to edit the SVGs I think.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably consider translation in this case. You need to add `80` translation for each letter (or less for some letter like `i` and `j`) and also increase the viewbox in order to contain all of them:

```css
svg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  stroke: #000;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.letter--a {
  stroke-width: 1px; 
  stroke:green;
}

.letter--f {
  stroke-width: 3px; 
  stroke:red;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 320 100">
  <path class="letter--a" d="M5,90
           l30,-80 30,80
           M20,50
           l30,0" />
  <path class="letter--f" transform=translate(80) d="M75,5
           l-60,0 0,90
           M15,45
           l50,0" />
  <path class="letter--i" transform=translate(160) d="M5,5
           l20,0 -10,0 0,85 -10,0 20,0" />
           
  <path class="letter--f" transform=translate(200) d="M75,5
           l-60,0 0,90
           M15,45
           l50,0" />
</svg>
```

An idea to have only a part of the letter visible is to consider `stroke-dasharray` and/or `stroke-dashoffset` and adjust the values as needed:

```css
svg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  stroke: #000;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.letter--a {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-dasharray: 84, 139;
}

.letter--f {
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-dasharray: 96, 145;
}

.letter--c {
  stroke-width: 8px;
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-dasharray: 84, 139;
}

.letter--c-b {
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke: yellow;
  stroke-dasharray: 84, 139;
  stroke-dashoffset: -89;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 100">
<path class="letter--a" d="M5,90
           l30,-80 30,80
           M20,50
           l30,0" />
<path class="letter--f" transform=translate(80) d="M75,5
           l-60,0 0,90
           M15,45
           l50,0" />
  <path class="letter--i" transform=translate(160) d="M5,5
           l20,0 -10,0 0,85 -10,0 20,0" />
           
  <path class="letter--f" transform=translate(200) d="M75,5
           l-60,0 0,90
           M15,45
           l50,0" />
  <path class="letter--c" transform=translate(280)  d="M60,10
           C-10,0 -10,100 60,90" /> 
  <path class="letter--c-b" transform=translate(280)  d="M60,10
           C-10,0 -10,100 60,90" /> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Ah, translate was what I missed. How feasible would it be to scramble the strokes? I assume each letter is 1 to 3 strokes. Could I have separate strokes for each letter and mix them or would that not work without the translate for each letter part?

Comment: @mplungjan yes sure you can ;) i updated my answer ... simply make the classe inside the path for each letter, then adjust the stroke with CSS and keep the default one inside path

Comment: Ah, I meant, can I have the left downstroke of the A on one line of code, Half a C on the next line of code, top arch of B on the next line, etc. I want to draw the letters in a random way

Comment: @mplungjan i see :) let me think about this ;)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. My idea is to scramble the instructions so it can be randomised how the letter is created

Comment: @mplungjan hmm i see ... well in this case i would prepare many classes for each letter (containing the stroke, stroke-dahsarray ,stroke-dashoffset,etc) then you can add the letter, you apply a random class to it ... you increment translation, you add next letter with class, and so on

Comment: Ohh. I really had hoped for "M60,10 C-10,0 -10,100 60,90\nM5,5 l20,0 -10,0 0,85 -10,0 20,0\n...." I am trying to make a captcha type dialog.

Comment: @mplungjan yes not easy to deal with paths like that ... we generally generate them using tools, i don't think there is people that are able to handle them easily withing code :)

Comment: Oh :( Ok. I thought I had a clever idea.

Comment: @mplungjan you can see here : https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp it's all  about maths and geometry so a bit tricky ... i guess the only way to do in this case is to consider dahsarray .. or wait a bit for some svg guru as am not the best one for this stuffs :)